# Adding image depends on ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I am getting responses from public API with using ajax calls. I want to display images depends on this responses. But I can not specify responses or create conditions outside of ajax call(can not read). How can I do that ?

Comment: cna you share your code

Comment: I recommend to take the stack overflow [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read thou the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is currently far too broad and open-ended for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: please share some code snippet and then specify what you need to achieve, it would be more helpful for you and people will be able to guide you, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery for example you  need to grab an HTML element within the callback function. For example:

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("http://yoururlapi", (data) => {
     const container = document.getElementById("container");
     container.append(`
        <img src="${data.imageUrl}" alt="Image alt" />
     `);
  });
})();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think a `promise` will help you with the issue.
I have tried to explain all of the code shown in the snippet.
Read more about `promise` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

async function callAjax(req) {
  let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // setTimeout is your ajax call where you have to wait
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (req === 'yourAjaxCall') {
        console.log('ajax success')
        // use when you know the ajax call is a success
        res({ content: 'success' });
        // use rej() if the ajax call is rejected
      }
    }, 1000);
  })
  
  return promise
}

async function run() {
  console.log('run')
  const sucsess = await callAjax('yourAjaxCall')

  content.innerHTML = `${sucsess.content}`
}

run()
```

```html
<div id="content"><div>
```